# Swift serial queue die in runtime

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

In my app i have a task with a lot of mathematics. If i run this task in main queue, i have frozen for a few seconds screen after each call of task, but it work. If i run task in other queue - from some random iteration it do nothing. If i run code in main queue, i get debug message in every iteration, in other queue - i get no one after random iteration. Looks like, the queue dying for some reasons. Usage of cpu and memory doesn't change and stay at level 50-70%. I think about endless loop, deadlock or something similar in function, but in main queue it always work fine. What goes wrong?

```
class MyClass {
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(
    label: "com.notrealcompany.hardMathematics", 
    qos: .userInteractive
)

func doStuff() {
    serialQueue.async {
        node.getArea()
        debugPrint("get area call")
    }
}
```

serialQueue is an instance variable, but situation don't change.

Comment: We need a reproducible example of the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) The above code snippet is insufficient to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `serialQueue` is being deallocated when the method your code is in returns. Try moving `serialQueue`'s declaration to an instance variable instead of a local variable.

```
class MyClass {
    let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(
        label: "com.notrealcompany.hardMathematics", 
        qos: .userInteractive
    )

    func doStuff() {
        serialQueue.async {
            node.getArea()
            debugPrint("get area call")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It was an instance member, i edit question. I try to change it to a local variable, but  it doesn't help. Queue label is unique and this queue is used only in this place.